# React + TS: How to call a method from outside of a React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-functional-component

Im wondering how I can call a method from outside of a React Functional Component. I wrote the function GetUsedLockers() which gets all the used lockers and returns amount. Now I want to call this function from another another component (OrgLocker.tsx) and display the data from the getUsedLockers() function there.

**OrgLockerTables.tsx**

```
const OrgLockerTables: React.FC = () => {


    const lockerCall = 'lockers';
    const [lockerData, setLockerData] = useState({
        id: 0,
        guid: "",
        is_currently_claimable: false
    }[""]);

    useEffect(() => {
        componentConsole().then((res) => {
            setLockerData(res);
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line   
    }, []);
    if (!lockerData) return (<div>Loading...</div>);


    //function to get all used lockers
    function getUsedLockers() {
        let amount = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < lockerData.length; i++) {
            if (!lockerData.is_currently_claimable) {
                amount++;
            }
        }
        console.log('log from getusedlockers, amount: ', amount)
        return (amount)
    }


    // function to get JSON data from the API
    function componentConsole(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            http.getRequest('/' + lockerCall).then((res) => {
                let data = res.data.data;

                console.log('data:', data);
                resolve(res.data.data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                reject();
            });
        })
    }
}
```

**OrgLocker.tsx**

```
import OrgLockerTables from '../tables/orgLockerTables';

const OrgLockers: React.FC = () => {

    let lockerTable = new OrgLockerTables();

    return (
        <div className="main-div-org">
        <p>Used</p>
        <p>{lockerTable.getUsedLockers()}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default OrgLockers;
```

When trying to make a call to OrgLockerTables and storing it in the lockerTable let it gives the following error:

> Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see many doubts... First, I imagine you've a parent component that saves the locker data when you call the request. You'd save this data inside LockerData, which is an array and finally you want to show it as OrgLockers each, right?

Answer (score 2):

I've restructured everything making it more understandable, I hope you don't mind according to what I think you want the comment above.

**locker-model.ts** - The type for the particular data being called back is found

```
export type Locker = {
  id: number;
  guid: string;
  isCurrentlyClaimable: boolean;
}
```

**locker-business.ts** - Where all the business logic is carried out, from the call for data to the calculation based on it

```
import { Locker } from "./locker-models";

const lockerCall = 'lockers';

const mockedData: Locker[] = [{
  id: 0,
  guid: "sample",
  isCurrentlyClaimable: false,     
},
{
  id: 1,
  guid: "sample2",
  isCurrentlyClaimable: true,     
},
{
  id: 2,
  guid: "sample3",
  isCurrentlyClaimable: true,     
}]

// Mocked function from your backend (componentConsole where you use lockerCall variable)
export const getLockersData = (): Promise<Locker[]> => Promise.resolve(mockedData);

export const getAmount = (lockers: Locker[]): number => {
  let amount = 0;

  !!lockers ? 
    lockers.filter(({isCurrentlyClaimable}) => { if(isCurrentlyClaimable) amount++ })
    : 0;

  return amount;
};
```

**index.tsx** - Here are both components that make the call to get the data and render the result you're looking for

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Locker } from './locker-models';
import { getLockersData, getAmount } from './locker-business';

import './style.css';

type OrgLockersProps = {
  amount: number;
}

const OrgLockers: React.FC<OrgLockersProps> = ({ amount }) => {
  return (
    <div className="main-div-org">
      <p>Lockers used:</p>
      <p>{amount}</p>
    </div>
  );
}


type OrgLockerTableProps = {};

const OrgLockerTable : React.FC<OrgLockerTableProps> = props => {
    const [lockerData, setLockerData] = React.useState<Locker[]>([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      getLockersData().then(response => setLockerData(response));
    }, []);

    const amount = getAmount(lockerData);

    return (
      <div>
        <OrgLockers amount={amount} />
      </div>
    );
};
```

You can see [the example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vtiqj5?file=index.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new .js file like Helpers.js and define export function with parameter it like that

```
export function getUsedLockers(lockerData) {
    let amount = 0;

    //Check your loop it can be like that
    for (let i = 0; i < lockerData.length; i++) {
        if (!lockerData[i].is_currently_claimable) {
            amount++;
        }
    }
    console.log('log from getusedlockers, amount: ', amount)
    return (amount)
}
```

Then import it where do you want to use.

```
import {getUsedLockers} from "../Helpers";
```

And use it like that:

```
const amount = getUsedLockers(data);
```